# Applet not carrying variables from init method to paint method

Tags: java, variables, applet, scope, init

This is an applet for my class.
Why is my final g.drawString printing 0's for all the variables i have in it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Days extends JApplet
{
private int month;

private int  day; 

private int  year_string,

private int total_days;

private int month_days;

public final int minMonth = 1; 

public final int maxMonth = 12; 

public final int minDay = 1; 

public final int maxDay = 31; 

public final int minYear = 1000; 

public final int maxYear = 2999;

public void init()
  {
    String month_string,
           day_string,
           year_string;

    month_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month (" + minMonth +
                                               "-" + maxMonth + ")");
    day_string   = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the day (" + minDay +
                                               "-" + maxDay + ")");
    year_string  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year (" + minYear +
                                               "-" + maxYear + ")");
     int month = Integer.parseInt( month_string );
     int day = Integer.parseInt( day_string );
     int year = Integer.parseInt( year_string );



    switch (month){
      case 1: 
              month_days = 0;
                 break;
      case 2: 
              month_days = 31;
                 break;
      case 3: 
              month_days = 59;
                 break;
      case 4: ;
              month_days = 90;
                 break;
      case 5: 
              month_days = 120;
                 break;
      case 6: 
              month_days = 151;
                 break;
      case 7: 
              month_days = 181;
                 break;
      case 8: 
              month_days = 212;
                 break;
      case 9: 
              month_days = 243;
                 break;
      case 10: 
              month_days = 273;
                 break;
      case 11:
               month_days = 304;
                  break;
      case 12: 
               month_days = 334;
                  break;        

        }

     int total_days = month_days + day;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {


     g.drawString("The number of days from the beginning of " + year_string + " to " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year_string +
                  "= " + total_days, 40, 30);

    showStatus("Alex Collins");
  }

}
```

Comment: and how can i fix this problem i'm having please help

Comment: You need to go thru a basic Java tutorial please google for one. please see our FAQ. this you have the same variable in the method init and in the class. So the var in the mehtod hides the class so it does not change it unless you use "this". in your case just remove the var declerations in init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source as posted does not compile here.  When the compilation error is fixed, it seems the problem is that variables are being declared as class attributes, as well as local to methods.  The locally declared attribute is 'shadowing' the other one we need, but disappears (goes out of scope) at the end of the method in which it is declared.

Note that:

1. Applets are harder to develop and debug than (frame based) applications.
2. Applications are harder to code than command line apps.
3. Variable scope is Java 101, and should be sorted out in command line apps.

Here is a working version of the applet.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Days extends JApplet
{
private int month;
private int  day;
private String  year_string;
private String  month_string;
private String  day_string;
private int total_days;
private int month_days;
public final int minMonth = 1;
public final int maxMonth = 12;
public final int minDay = 1;
public final int maxDay = 31;
public final int minYear = 1000;
public final int maxYear = 2999;

public void init()
  {
    month_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month (" + minMonth +
                                               "-" + maxMonth + ")");
    day_string   = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the day (" + minDay +
                                               "-" + maxDay + ")");
    year_string  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year (" + minYear +
                                               "-" + maxYear + ")");
     int month = Integer.parseInt( month_string );
     int day = Integer.parseInt( day_string );
     int year = Integer.parseInt( year_string );



    switch (month){
      case 1:
              month_days = 0;
                 break;
      case 2:
              month_days = 31;
                 break;
      case 3:
              month_days = 59;
                 break;
      case 4: ;
              month_days = 90;
                 break;
      case 5:
              month_days = 120;
                 break;
      case 6:
              month_days = 151;
                 break;
      case 7:
              month_days = 181;
                 break;
      case 8:
              month_days = 212;
                 break;
      case 9:
              month_days = 243;
                 break;
      case 10:
              month_days = 273;
                 break;
      case 11:
               month_days = 304;
                  break;
      case 12:
               month_days = 334;
                  break;

        }
     total_days = month_days + day;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
     g.drawString("The number of days from the beginning of " + year_string + " to " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year_string +
                  "= " + total_days, 10, 30);
    showStatus("Alex Collins");
  }
}
```